# Can someone explain the logic behind this? Why in the 'for' loop is it <12? How can the i var be over 2 in the array?

Tags: javascript

I see this similar question asked in the java section. But i am just using 1 for loop. Why in the for() loop is it i<12?? I am not understanding the logic of that. There are only 3 variables in the episodes array. Can someone lead me in the right direction to understand this? I was just doing some practice on openclassroom.com.

```
class Episode {
  constructor(title, duration, hasBeenWatched) {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.hasBeenWatched = hasBeenWatched;
  }
}

let firstEpisode = new Episode('Dark Beginnings', 45, true);
let secondEpisode = new Episode('The Mystery Continues', 45, false);
let thirdEpisode = new Episode('An Unexpected Climax', 60, false);

// Create your array here
// ====================================

let episodes = [firstEpisode, secondEpisode, thirdEpisode];

// ====================================

const body = document.querySelector('body');

for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++) { //this <12 i don't understand
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('series-frame');
  let newTitle = document.createElement('h2');
  newTitle.innerText = 'The Story of Tau';
  let newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  newParagraph.innerText = `${episodes[i].title}
    ${episodes[i].duration} minutes
    ${episodes[i].hasBeenWatched ? 'Already been watched' : 'Not yet watched'}`;
  newDiv.append(newTitle);
  newDiv.append(newParagraph);
  body.append(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: And thank you all for any help I can get. Thank you!!

Comment: I doubt there's any explanation other than whoever wrote the code did so incorrectly. It should be `i < episodes.length` optimally.

Comment: @Jacob the only explanation I can think of is that this code was taken from another place where the author of it had statically looped over 12 times

Comment: Yes!! that works. Thank you very much.

Comment: `openclassroom.com` - perhaps the point was to fix the bug in the code

Comment: @Jaromanda X No that wasn't the point, they had it in there code and it was working on codepen. https://codepen.io/nicolaspatschkowski/pen/KKpEWzJ I couldnt figure that out. It didn't work in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sense of using 12 in forLoop. However you can use `episodes.length` to iterate over episodes array

```js
class Episode {
  constructor(title, duration, hasBeenWatched) {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.hasBeenWatched = hasBeenWatched;
  }
}

let firstEpisode = new Episode('Dark Beginnings', 45, true);
let secondEpisode = new Episode('The Mystery Continues', 45, false);
let thirdEpisode = new Episode('An Unexpected Climax', 60, false);

// Create your array here
// ====================================

let episodes = [firstEpisode, secondEpisode, thirdEpisode];

// ====================================

const body = document.querySelector('body');

for(let i = 0; i < episodes.length; i++) { //this <12 i don't understand
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('series-frame');
  let newTitle = document.createElement('h2');
  newTitle.innerText = 'The Story of Tau';
  let newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  newParagraph.innerText = `${episodes[i].title}
    ${episodes[i].duration} minutes
    ${episodes[i].hasBeenWatched ? 'Already been watched' : 'Not yet watched'}`;
  newDiv.append(newTitle);
  newDiv.append(newParagraph);
  body.append(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent all day trying to figure out why <12 was in there, it seemed to work on the openclassrooms site and I cant figure out why. Thank you so very much for your help.